# Doubly Linked list in c++...previous pointer showing garbage value in second iteration?

Tags: c++

1+3-2 
this is the expression i am reading from file and trying to evaluate 
while doing 1+3 i get my temp pointer on + and temp->previous has value 1 and all works fine then i get 4-2  but when i evaluate this and get my temp pointer on - 
temp->previous shows garbage value instead of showing 4.....please help

```
void evaluate(list *temp, char operator)
 {
    temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {


   if (temp->next->operatorval == operator)
        {

    if (oper == '/')
    temp->previous->floatval = temp->previous->floatval / temp->next->floatval;

    else if (oper == '*')
    temp->previous->floatval = temp->previous->floatval * temp->next->floatval;

    else if (oper == '+')
    temp->previous->floatval = temp->previous->floatval + temp->next->floatval;

    else if (oper == '-')
    temp->previous->floatval = temp->previous->floatval - temp->next->floatval;

    temp = temp->previous;

            removeNext(temp, temp->next, 1);
            removeNext(temp, temp->next, 2);



        }


        temp = temp->next;
    }


}
```

Comment: removeNext function deletes the temp->next and join temp         with temp->next->next

Comment: This seems odd to be doing with a linked list rather than a simple stack.

Comment: this is my assignment...and linked list is first requirment

Comment: If this is an educational exercise, hopefully the object-oriented design nature of C++ comes into play. `list.pop()` is a lot more conventional than `removeNext(list, list->next, 1)`. The Standard Library provides many examples of the typical method names used.

Comment: can you please explain what list.pop() will do here?

Comment: Remove a link in the chain, for example. You need a stack to solve problems like this, it's not a loop you're building. You can implement a stack with a linked list if you prefer, but the basic operators like `pop`, `push`, `shift` and `unshift` are the conventional names.